# Optimal Flow Distribution

Tags: algorithm, optimization, network-flow

I've searched stackoverflow and google but I haven't found someone with quite the same type of problem.

[Optimal distribution of power plants on a city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122077/optimal-distribution-of-power-plants-on-a-city) seemed like the closest solution to this problem but I believe my problem is simplier than the question there and therefore would have a better solution than bruteforce.

The problem is this:
I have 9 cities, each producing power and using power. Each city is connected to the other 8 cities. How can I determine the best way to send excess power to the cities that need it with the minimum amount of energy transfered?

I've tried to do this problem with network flow, utilizing multiple sources and sinks but it does work correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Assume each city is producing x amount of energy, and using y, if x > y, than that city is just producing x-y energy, if not, than is using right? so you can do this trick, after that you will have only cities that produces exclusivly or uses energy... than may be to run maximum flow for all positive vertexes?

Comment: What do you mean, "the best way"? How you define which way is better?

Comment: Maybe you want a min-cost flow?

Comment: I added a line to qualify "best" -- The minimum amount of energy needed to power the entire system.

Comment: If a city can produce power `p1` but needs `p2` where `p2 > p1`, then `p2 - p1` power must be transfered to that city. Find the sum over all cities that cannot produce as much power as they need. That is how much power has to be transfered from cities with excess power. You cannot transfer less and power all cities; there is no need to transfer more. Where is the difficulty? Are there capacity limits or costs you have not told us about?

Comment: Are connections between cities differs by transfer cost? Otherwise it seems that any greedy algorithm is sufficient (use as much energy as needed, send excess to random city in demand).

Comment: Initially I have 9 cities, but at the end there would be something like 800 cities, each having at max 8 connections to each other. The problem is to figure out the minimum amount of energy that you would need to power the entire grid, whilst minimizing the amount of edges the power would need to traverse through to reach another city that needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this article](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/flowext.pdf). That is how you can reduce your problem to min-cost max-flow.

For every city, calculate demand `d` as `usage - production`. Group cities by `d=0`, `d<0` and `d>0`. Let all connections have infinite capacity. Then add two new nodes, sink and source. Add edges between source and `d<0` nodes, with capacity `|d|`. Add edges between `d>0` and sink nodes, with capacity `d`. Now you have single-source single-sink network, and you can apply any min-cost max-flow algorithm to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard Distribution Network Optimization Problem. Define 2 sets of decision variables 
Xi : Power produced by ith city , 
Yij : Power consumed by ith city where j is the supplying city

Define the transmission cost for transfer of power from one city to other

Objective : min ∑ Cij * Yij for all i,j

constraints :
demand constraint : Xi +  ∑Yij (for all js) <= Total power req of city i
similarly supply constraint

Hope this works